Issue is on the onchange method in headerComponentFramework
I am adding no of empty row in ad grid though this method
gridOptions.api.updateRowData({ add: [emptyObj] })

After adding the row, each row has text box for the column.
On click of the text box i am rendering on component  though this
headerComponentFramework: ABCHeaderComponent, 

In the ABCHeaderComponent html file i have a textbox, where i have change functionality. so when i am performing any change operation, one change method is getting triggered in ABCHeaderComponent.ts file,
the issue is below
If i add 2 rows in the grid, and i am doing the change operation in the 2nd row (index value 1), but the value is getting update in the both the index
on change method i tried in the below way
param.node.data.{nameofthecoulmfield} = ngModel variable of the input text

if i am doing the change in the index o, index 1 value should not get updated
